# Using snort with cloudflare?

Tags: ids

How might Snort or another IDS system work with Cloudflare? Essentially, the originating IP would be CloudFlare's, therefore a proactive IPS might be difficult to install.

I understand that Cloudflare itself is a IPS to some degree and will actively detect some attack signatures, but is it feasible to install something else between Cloudflare and a web server?

Comment: This is probably a better question to ask CloudFlare directly.

Answer (score 0):

CloudFlare probably injects a header called X-Forwarded-For or X-Client-IP that you could read. However, [a] this can be faked and [2] it won't stop any attacks at layers 3 or 4 because the traffic really comes from CloudFlare.